# Как подключиться к БД через туннель?

Tags: tunnel, база-данных, php

Добрый день.

Пользуюсь программой Devart MySqlStudio. Хочу подключиться к базе на хостинге, но по умолчанию там права закрыты для подключения с внешних компьютеров.

Читал про Tunnel.php - раньше когда-то даже работало, а сейчас делаю, как [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-dcqouPheg#t=53), но пишет ошибку при подключению к мойсайт/tunnel.php.  Ошибка:

```
Devart HttpTunnel v1.72
    Required function set_time_limit does not exist.
    Required PHP functions listed above are not available. Tunneling script will not work without these functions. Please read PHP manuals about how to install listed functions.
```

Подскажите, как мне подключиться к БД, не используя phpMyAdmin? Спасибо.

Comment: Да почему кодом-то оформлено?

Comment: a SSH на хостинге тоже нет ? просто даже на самом дешевом хостинге опционально можно включить SSH

Answer (score 1):

А, собственно, зачем вам туннели какие-то и прочая ерунда?

Я так понял, вы коннектитесь к базе по логину \ паролю? Ну так дайте пользователю права на доступ к базе извне, и всё, чем геморрой городить.

Либо простенький приёмник напишите, который и будет работать  с базой.

Comment: К базе можно зайти непосредственно из кода php либо phpMyAdmin. Я пользуюсь программой Devart MySqlStudio.Она намного лучше phpMyAdmin. Но подключиться так просто к БД нельзя - почти на всех хостингах доступ снаружи закрыт. Вот и пытаюсь придумать, как получить доступ к базе.

Comment: я так понимаю, ограничения в MySQL на подключения только с localhost